# MYSQL query to get SUM based on another table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `goods_ages` (
  `resourceKey` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `eraId` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

| resourceKey| eraId       | 
|:-----------|------------:|
| gold       |      1      | 
| iron       |      1      |  
| wood       |      2      |  
| steel      |      2      |  


CREATE TABLE `user_resources` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `gold` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iron` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wood` int(10) DEFAULT NULL
  `steel` int(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


| id | date       | gold | iron | wood | steel|
|:---|------------|------|------|------|------|
| 1  |  2020-09-02|  90  |  5   |  55  |  10  |
| 2  |  2020-09-03|  50  |  10  |  55  |  10  |
| 3  |  2020-09-04|  30  |  20  |  55  |  30  |
| 4  |  2020-09-05|  50  |  20  |  55  |  20  |
```

And want to display the SUM of resource per `eraId` at specific dates (in an area chart):

```
| eraId   |    date      |  SUM   | 
|:--------|--------------|-------:|
| 1       |   2020-09-02 |   95   | 
| 2       |   2020-09-02 |   65   |
| 1       |   2020-09-03 |   60   | 
| 2       |   2020-09-03 |   65   |
| 1       |   2020-09-04 |   50   | 
| 2       |   2020-09-04 |   85   |
| 1       |   2020-09-05 |   70   | 
| 2       |   2020-09-05 |   75   |
```

My problem is that I can't figure out to build my MYSQL query. I would need something like

```
SELECT user_resources.SUM, goods_ages.eraId, user_resources.date FROM user_resources INNER JOIN goods_ages GROUP BY goods_ages.eraID
```

But also need a sub query to get the some for each eraId...

PS: I have over 150 columns in user_resources and there may be more added automatically in the future.

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names, alarm bells should start ringing. Consider revising your schema design.

Comment: Well, there are not really enumerated. I just wanted to simplify. I will update the question

Comment: Still, they're all the same kind of thing. A revised design will improve things.

Comment: I have an Id (which I omitted in my sample) in the goods_ages table. Do you recommend to have one entry in user_resources referring to the id in goods_ages, for each day, for each player? That would mean 150+ entries per day per player...

Comment: If you need to track 150 resources per player per day, then yes.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will redesign then!